# How do I resize a Linux filesystem data .bin file?

Tags: filesystem, binary

I have a 2 MB file: root.bin, that is a Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem, and I would like to expand it so that I can put more files in it, but it does not just resize like I thought it would. How do I resize it, preferably keeping the files on it, to a specific size?

Comment: Is your specific confusion that you have increased the size of the file, but the filesystem it contains doesn't seem to have changed to match?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We will try to make your two MB `root.bin` file to a 12 MB to demonstrate the steps.

---

Create a copy of your file (just in case for backup purpose):

```
cp root.bin 12mb.bin
```

Run this command to add 10M to the file size:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=12mb.bin bs=1MiB count=10 conv=notrunc oflag=append
```

Now 12mb.bin is not 2M any more, actually its size is 12M.

Run:

```
e2fsck -f 12mb.bin
```

to check the filesystem on the file, then run:

```
resize2fs 12mb.bin
```

Done. mount it somewhere:

```
sudo mount 12mb.bin /mnt
```

check the size:

```
df -h --output=size /mnt/
Size
 12M
```

And the existence of files:

```
ls /mnt
```

---

We can also use `losetup` to act with the file like a block device:

```
sudo losetup -f 12mb.bin
```

then:

```
sudo losetup -l | grep -i "12mb.bin" | awk '{print $1}'
/dev/loop0
```

and we can resize `/dev/loop0`.

Comment: The `dd` command doesn't overwrite the original contents

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen No it does not. we are using `notrunc` and `append`. and it shouldn't right?

Comment: Your right sorry I am accessing from mobile didn't see those options almost thought you were using some esoteric code. Always nice to follow your answer always a teaching moment for me

Comment: Rather than using `dd` to expand the file, why not just use [`truncate`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate)?

Comment: @Carcer That's also a good option, I just used to use `dd` ...

Comment: No need to use `sudo` for `e2fsck` and `resize2fs`.